# how to split large dataset as quickly as possible

Tags: sas

I have a very large dataset of size 1T, I need to split it into several sub-datasets quickly.

the following is the traditional way to split a dataset:

```
Data d1 d2...dn;
Set raw_dataset;
if condition1 then output d1;
else if condition2 then output d2;
...
else if conditionN then output dn;
run;
```

but it's still too slow for me!!
Is there any method which could speed up the process?

Comment: Depending on what the condition is you could add an index to the raw dataset.

Comment: Too slow how ? How long do you let the split run and how far along is it when you 'break' the submission ?  How many rows and variables are there in the dataset? How many splits are you making? Can you show an example of the splitting criteria? What kind of hardware on you on ? Is the raw_dataset on a local drive? Are you writing to a network or cloud destination ? Why do you feel you need to split the data... can you index the dataset appropriately for rapid retrieval of pertinent subsets ? Have you checked the system event viewer for disk I/o errors?

Comment: Do you have access to the SPDE libname engine or SAS/CONNECT? Either of these could be used to obtain some degree of paralellism.

Comment: Have you tried to compress= output dataset?

Comment: How complex are the filtering conditions? Sometimes data set options are more efficient or other methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following macro, just input two parameters
1. the input dataset you want to split
2. enter maximum observations you need in each dataset

```
options merror mprint symbolgen mlogic;

/****CHANGE PATH for input DS location****/
libname inp "Y:\InputDS";
libname outp "Y:\OutputDS";

data inp_ds;
 set inp.input_sample; /****CHANGE Input DS****/
run;

proc sql noprint;
select count(*) into: total_obs from inp_ds;
quit;

%let max_obs=20000; /****CHANGE max number of OBS in a split DS****/
%let split_ds_num_temp=%sysfunc(int(&total_obs/&max_obs));
%let remainder= %sysfunc(mod(&total_obs,&max_obs));

data find_num;
 if &remainder>0 then split_ds_num=&split_ds_num_temp+1;
 else split_ds_num=&split_ds_num_temp;
 call symput('no_of_splits',split_ds_num);
run;

%macro split(i,inds);
data outp.out&i;
 set &inds;
 %if &i=1 %then 
 %do;
    If _N_>=1 and _N_<=&max_obs Then Output;
 %end;
 %else %if &i>1 %then
 %do;
    If _N_ >=(&max_obs*(&i-1))+1 and _N_<=&max_obs*&i Then Output;
 %end;
run;
%mend split;

data initiate_macro;
do i = 1 to &no_of_splits;
    call execute('%split('||i||', inp_ds)');
end;
run;
```

This will create multiple output datasets as : out1 out2... outn ..depending upon the no of observations in the output directory path mentioned in your program

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use conditions, I can share with you this macro wich I am using since 3 years :

```
%macro partitionner(Library=, Table=, nb_part=, nblig=, tabIntr=);
data 
    %do i=1 %to &nb_part; 
        &Library..&tabIntr.&i. 
     %end;
; 
      set &Library..&Table.; 

      %do i=1 %to %eval(&nb_part-1); 
         if _n_ >= %eval(1+(&i.-1)*&nblig.) and _n_ <= %eval(&i.*&nblig.) 
         then output &Library..&tabIntr.&i.; 
      %end; 
      if _n_>=%eval((&i.-1)*&nblig+1) then output &lib..&tabIntr.&nb_part.; 
   run;
%mend partitionner;
```

**where :**

- Library : the name of the Library where is the table to split and the
  results.
- Table : the name of the table to split.
- nb_part : number of the tables wich are results from the split.
- nblig : number of rows in each output table.
- tabIntr : the name of the tables outputed (prefix).

**example :**

bigTable has 100 rows, and it is in LIBRA library. Want to split it in 4 tables, each one has 33 rows.

```
%partitionner(Library=LIBRA, Table=bigTable, nb_part=4, nblig=33, tabIntr=smalTable);
```

The results is :

- smalTable1 has 33 observations.
- smalTable2 has 33 observations.
- smalTable3 has 33 observations.
- smalTable4 has 1 observations.